# How to apply Hexadecimal mask to a xml variable in a xml res/drawable file?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I have this xml file, and i have to apply a mask `&#111111` to a variable color called `@color/personal_color`

```
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="10dip" />
         <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#706969" />
         <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/personal_color&#111111" android:endColor="#BB7e7a7a" />            
     </shape>
 </item>
```

This `android:startColor="@color/personal_color&#111111"` gives me this error `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'startColor' with value '@color/personal_colorð›ˆ‡').`

How to solve this?